# Множественный insert

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, insert

Помогите пожалуйста построить запрос.

Есть база с 3 таблицами: люди, автомобили, связи людей с автомобилями (у каждого человека может быть много автомобилей)

```
create table peoples (
 id integer primary key autoincrement,
 fio text,
 ...
);

create table cars (
 id integer primary key autoincrement,
 car text,
 ...
);

create table relations (
 id integer primary key autoincrement,
 fio_id integer,
 car_id integer
);
```

Есть ли способ за один запрос вставить: нового человека (в таблицу peoples) и сразу же привязать к нему автомобиль (в таблице relations)

По сути вопрос о том, как вставить id записи, которая только что создана.

Длинный способ:

1. insert fio человека в таблицу peoples
2. поиск id человека по fio в таблице peoples (потому что в следующем шаге нужен именно id)
3. insert id человека и id автомобиля в таблицу relations

Может как-то проще можно?
А может есть возможность сразу в три таблицы вставлять? (было бы вообще здорово)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А может есть возможность сразу в три таблицы вставлять?

Нет. SQLite (да и все иные СУБД) поддерживают исключительно однотабличный INSERT. Некоторые СУБД (например, Постгресс) позволяют выполнять вставку в CTE - но SQLite к ним не относится. Так что увы, три таблицы - три INSERT.

А вот пункты 2 и 3 можно совместить в один запрос - используйте INSERT .. SELECT, a не INSERT .. VALUES:

```sql
INSERT INTO peoples (fio, ...)
VALUES ('Адам Казимирович Козлевич', ...)
ON CONFLICT (...) ...;

INSERT INTO cars (car, ...)
VALUES ('Антилопа Гну', ...)
ON CONFLICT (...) ...;

INSERT INTO relations (fio_id, car_id)
SELECT MAX(peoples.id), MAX(cars.id)
FROM peoples, cars
WHERE peoples.fio = 'Адам Казимирович Козлевич'
  AND cars.car = 'Антилопа Гну';
```

`MAX()` позволяет выбрать последнюю вставленную запись при наличии полностью совпадающих ФИО и/или наименования машины. Либо для однозначного выбора в последнем запросе нужны дополнительные условия отбора - но следует гарантировать, что его SELECT-часть вернёт строго одну запись (в самом крайнем случае - добавить сортировку и LIMIT).